# Translating Wordpress (WooCommerce plugin) using php filters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, translation

I am trying to translate my WooCommerce page to my native language using php filterss (add_filter() function).
I got one example where I took a hook of the page and used it to easily translate a button without any issue.

```
add_filter('ultimate_woocommerce_auction_bid_button_text', 'woo_custom_bid_button_text');
function woo_custom_bid_button_text() {
  return __( 'Přihodit', 'woo_ua' );
}
```

"Přihodit" is a translation to my native language of "Place bid".

Problem is when I want to translate part right in front of the button which says "Bid Value"

This is WooCommerce source code:

```
            <div class="quantity buttons_added">
            <label for="uwa_your_bid"><?php _e('Bid Value', 'woo_ua') ?>:</label>
            <input type="number" name="uwa_bid_value" data-auction-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>"
            value=""min="<?php echo $product->woo_ua_bid_value()  ?>"
            step="any" size="<?php echo strlen($product->get_woo_ua_current_bid())+2 ?>" title="bid"  class="input-text qty  bid text left">
            </div>
```

I have already tried using same method as I used above:

```
add_filter('ultimate_woocommerce_auction_before_bid_button', 'woo_custom_text_before_bid_input'`enter code here`);
function woo_custom_text_before_bid_input() {
  return _e('Příhoz', 'woo_ua');
}
```

But I cant get this to work since theres not a specific hook to use. Thanks to any replies or solutions in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [gettext filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext)

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text, $text, $domain ){

    if ( $text == 'Bid Value' )
        $translated_text = 'Příhoz';

    return $translated_text;

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This code hides "nulls" everything on the site. I mean all texts and articles are missing now. Not even the translation is there.

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe you copied the old code from it?

Comment: Okay.. I dont understand the code at all, but it really works. You are a live saver! Thanks a lot!
Maybe could u do me a favor and explain the code itself? For example I dont understand why the last row contains ", 10, 3 );"

Is that just PRIORITY and ACCEPTED ARGS from add_filter() syntax?

Comment: Yes exactly. Those arguments are the priority and accepted args. You can find more details here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Comment: Yeah. I have already read that documentation multiple times to understand add_filter() function. Just asked to be sure. Thanks again:)